# How to sync three swiper slider?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I have three different slider with different number of slide visible on each. How do I keep all three different swiper slider in sync? I do know for two slider we can do something like this:

```
sliderOne.controller.control = sliderTwo;
sliderTwo.controller.control = sliderOne;
```

I want when someone change sliderOne to change sliderTwo and sliderThree also and vice-versa. When I do something like this:

```
sliderOne.controller.control = sliderTwo;
sliderTwo.controller.control = sliderOne;
sliderThree.controller.control = sliderOne;
```

sliderThree is able to change/control sliderOne but sliderOne is only controlling sliderTwo not both sliderTwo and sliderThree.

Can anyone suggest me how to change sliderTwo and sliderThree both through sliderOne? Think like sliderOne is thumbnails for both sliderTwo and sliderThree.

Comment: What you're looking for is [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass array to `controller.control`

So final code will be

```
sliderOne.controller.control = [sliderTwo, sliderThree];
```

Link to the docs: [Docs](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#controller)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'control')

Answer (score 2):

You can redeclare the `setTranslate` & `setTransition` if sizes are the same:

```
function bindSwipers(...swiperList) {
    for (const swiper of swiperList) {
        swiper.setTranslate = function(translate, byController, doNotPropagate){
            if (doNotPropagate) {
                Swiper.prototype.setTranslate.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                for (const swiper of swiperList) {
                    swiper.setTranslate(translate, byController, true);
                }
            }
        };
        swiper.setTransition = function(duration, byController, doNotPropagate){
            if (doNotPropagate) {
                Swiper.prototype.setTransition.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                for (const swiper of swiperList) {
                    swiper.setTransition(duration, byController, true);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
bindSwipers(sliderOne, sliderTwo, sliderThree);
```

or `slideTo`:

```
function bindSwipers(...swiperList) {
    for (const swiper of swiperList) {
        swiper.slideTo = function(index, speed, runCallbacks, doNotPropagate){
            if (doNotPropagate) {
                Swiper.prototype.slideTo.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                for (const swiper of swiperList) {
                    swiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks, true);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
bindSwipers(sliderOne, sliderTwo, sliderThree);
```

Comment: From your question, we cannot understand what's the issue, please consider depicting the issue in the question itself, besides the title.